# Instagram API Pagination : Next page

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get all the recent media by tag using [this](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) Instagram endpoint. The purpose here is to track all the recent media for tags. I have configured a scheduled task (with Java and Spring) (to execute every hour) that sends requests and gets data. Below is the execution sequence:

- Send the GET request to Instagram and previously stored `max_tag_id` (send with null if there's no previous id)
- Iterate through results, extract `next_max_tag_id` from pagination element and store it in the database against corresponding tag
- Send GET request again with new `max_tag_id` and continue
- Stop if `next_url` in the result is null or number of media returned is less than 20 (configured)

Once the execution finishes, next execution (after let's say an hour) will start with previously stored max_tag_id.

The issue I am seeing is, I never get 'recent' documents in subsequent executions. As per the documentation, passing `max_tag_id` in the request should return all the media **after** that id, however it's not happening. I keep getting old media.

If I want to get the recent documents in every execution, do I need to pass `null` `max_id` in the first request of every execution?  If I do that, will I not get redundant documents in every execution? I tried asking Instagram but haven't got any response. Also, their documentation explains little about pagination. Not sure whether pagination for recent media endpoint works backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want most recent don't use `max_tag_id`, If you use `max_tag_id` it will return all media dated before that.

You need to get the `min_tag_id` and store it, in the next hour start by making call with only `min_tag_id`, if there is `pagination.next_url`, use that to get next set of 20, until `pagination.next_url` does not exist.... use the stored `min_tag_id` to make calls the next hour.

The very first time you make call without `max_tag_id` or `min_tag_id`

You can also set the `&count=32`, to get 32 posts with every API call, (32 is max from my experience)

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer Krisrak, you are a life saver :)